# Reuse iam_instance_profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have spun up an instance in AWS using terraform. I created a policy to add to a role I created to add to an instance profile I created all using terraform. Everything worked as intended and I can see this role is associated with my instance when I check the AWS console.

Now, is there a way for me to reuse this profile/role on a new instance?
I have not destroyed instance one so the role still exists.

I have tried

```
  iam_instance_profile = "Instance Profile ARNs(copied directly from the role)"
```

I have also tried using the name of the role "web_iam_role", the instance profile "web_instance_profile" to no avail.

So is there a way for me to reuse this role?
Do I create a new instance profile every time I spin up server and associate the role to that instance profile? If so how do I construct that code?

Edit:

```
#Node 1

provider "aws" {
  profile =                 var.profile
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  region =                  var.aws_region
}


//Role
resource "aws_iam_role" "web_iam_role" {
    name = "web_iam_role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

//Instance Profile
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "web_instance_profile" {
    name = "web_instance_profile"
    role = "web_iam_role"
}

//Role policy
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "web_iam_role_policy" {
  name = "web_iam_role_policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.web_iam_role.id}"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::gk-bucket-1"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::gk-bucket-1/*"]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_instance" "Node 1" {
  ami = var.amis_ubuntu_18_04
  instance_type = var.instance_type_t2_micro
  subnet_id = var.public_subnets
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.web_instance_profile.id}"

  security_groups = ["sg-**********"]

  key_name = var.Keypair

  tags = {
   
  }
}
```

The code above works as desired, allowing me to access the buckets I need.
I want to spin up another server using another terraform script with the same access to the same bucket but don't want to recreate the entire role again as it already exists. Ideally I want to spin up many servers at different times so creating the same role repeatedly seems unnecessary.

```
    #Node 2
provider "aws" {
  profile =                 var.profile
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  region =                  var.aws_region
}



resource "aws_instance" "Node 2" {
  ami = var.amis_ubuntu_18_04
  instance_type = var.instance_type_t2_micro
  subnet_id = var.public_subnets
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  iam_instance_profile = "web_instance_profile"

  security_groups = ["sg-***************"]

  key_name = var.Keypair

  tags = {
   
  }
}
```

How can I reuse this role? All the documentation I find involves creating the role but none involve using an existing one.

Comment: What does the arn look like? You are aware of the differences between a role and an instance profile? They are different resources: `"arn:aws:iam::****:instance-profile/test-***-emr-worker-role"` vs `arn:aws:iam::****:role/test-::****-emr-worker-role`

Comment: Can you please share your Terraform code, ideally as a [mcve] so that people can see what you've already tried? If it errors then you should show the full error (including the context of where the error occurs). If it doesn't error but just doesn't do what you want it to do then it would help if you showed what it is doing and how that differs from what you want.

Comment: I am aware role and instance profile are different but I don't know how to reuse resources that are already there. I added the code to demonstrate what I am trying to. Apologies if this seems like a simple question but I am relatively new to terraform. I have tried copying the "Instance Profile ARNs" directly but that throws an error also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the role and instance profile once. And you can associate the instance profile with multiple ec2 instances using the iam_instance_profile argument. If you did this, please paste the error.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_instance_profile

If the instance profile and ec2 instance are not in same tf template, you can reference an existing instance profile - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_instance_profile

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help. It actually worked using my code above but I am not sure what I was doing incorrectly the first time. 'iam_instance_profile = "web_instance_profile"'

Comment: The argument expects the instance profile name. The template you pasted references the id of your instance profile. it should be .name not .id